# How to throw an exception when your method returns a Future in a test?

Tags: scala, scalatest

So I have a method in `TokenService` called `useToken`:

```
def useToken(token: String): Future[T] = {
// returns either an instance of T or throws a ServerException
}
```

This is wrapped inside another class say `AuthService`:

```
def useTokenForAuth(token: String): Future[AuthTokenData] = {
  tokenService.useToken(token) 
}
```

In my test, I'm mocking the `useToken` to throw an Exception like:

```
when(
  mockTokenService.useToken("fake-token")
).thenThrow(new ServerException)

mockAuthService.useTokenForAuth("fake-token")
```

and `mockAuthService` does not throw an Exception. Could it be because the return type is a `Future`?

Comment: Can you please complete the details? Where is `T` coming from in `def useToken(token: String): Future[T] = {`? What is `tokenService`? I don't think it is because of the future

Comment: Don't throw exception, use `Future.failed`

Comment: @cchantep, exception can be thrown. It can test something else than `Future.failed`.

Comment: A lot of thing "can" be done, not that's a good practice. If you want to explicitly have a failed  `Future`, use the appropriate factory rather than throwing an exception that have to caught before being wrapped up in a failed `Future`

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad practice. If there is logic before the asynchronous operation that can throw, and you want to test it, this is the way.